# Ergodicity and Positive Recurrence

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

If a stochastic process $\{ X_t \}_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$, that takes values only in $\mathcal{X} = \{0, 1\}$, is ergodic, then what can we say about its recurrence times? If $T_k$ is the $k$th recurrence time for the state $1$, then is $\mathbb{E}[T_k]$ finite? What about $\mathbb{E}[T^{2}_{k}]$, or other moments of $T_{k}$?

Comment: The expected value is finite, in fact its reciprocal is the invariant distribution up to normalization. I think in the finite state space case you can actually prove that it has all finite moments.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The result, you say, surely holds when the process $X_t$ is Markov. Does it naturally extend when $X_t$ is ergodic? How do I prove this?

Comment: What is the definition of ergodicity of a non-Markov process?

Comment: For any measurable function $g$, if $\mathbb{E}[|g(X_1)|] < +\infty$ then the sequence of random variables $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^{T}g(X_t)$ converges a.s. as $T \rightarrow \infty$, and is equal to $\mathbb{E}[g(X_1)]$

Comment: The above is the definition of ergodicity that I am using. It is from Durrett's book, Chap. 7.

Comment: For a finite state space, by considering $g$ to be the indicator of each singleton, it is equivalent to say that the expected occupation fractions converge, and the occupation fractions are basically the reciprocal of the recurrence times by the same logic as in the Markov case.

Comment: Sorry, I should say that just the occupation fractions converge a.s., not on average.